# Perimeter of bounding box of an image

Tags: c++, opencv

I need to find perimeter of bounding box of an image in OpenCV using C++. When using `double perimeter = arcLength(rois[wp],true);` the following error is generated:

```
Assertion failed (count >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S)) in arcLength,
file /home/vidushi/Desktop/OpenCV/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp,
line 285 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  /home/vidushi/Desktop/OpenCV/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp:285: 
error: (-215) count >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function arcLength
```

Can someone explain what could be the problem?

Comment: In order to complete the answer below, how are you declaring `rois`?

Comment: Why don't you compute the perimeter simply as: `2*(rect.width+rect.height);`)

Comment: yes sir @Miki I have computed perimeter like this only

Answer (score 1):

Basically that the format of `rois[wp]` is not accepted by the `arcLength` function. It must be 2D and have a CV_32S or CV_32F depth. Something like `cv::Mat valid_roi(n, 2, CV_32F);` (adapt to your problem).

Comment: rois is declared as vector<Mat> rois;. rois is basically connected component of image. So if there are 2 connected component in an image vector rois contain so 2 matrices.and rois is gray-scale image obtained after performing gaussian blur,morphological , otsu binarization operation. My objective is detection of tables in an image.

Comment: Right, it must be gray-scale to work with the algorithm.

Comment: [`arcLength`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#double%20arcLength(InputArray%20curve,%20bool%20closed)) needs a list of 2D points, so if input is a matrix, it must be initialised similar to the example above. You can use `CV_32S` if your components are integers.

Comment: i calculated perimeter using formulae = 2 * (l+h)